# How to handle those specific exceptions from repository? (Android Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-authentication, repository, android-mvvm

I'm new to android and I'm developing a few applications for studying. 
I've been trying to improve a code that I have but I got stuck in the following problem:
I'm creating a new user, validating it with Google Firebase. I managed to create a user normally but I'm not able to handle with one exception from the register moment which is the "FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException". 
I created a class to handle a most of exceptions from email/password mistakes:

```
class AddUser(private val repository: UserRepository) {

    @Throws(InvalidUserException::class)
    suspend operator fun invoke(user: UserModel) {
        if(user.email.isEmpty()) {
            throw InvalidUserException("Email cannot be empty")
        }
        if(!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(user.email).matches()) {
            throw InvalidUserException("Email is not valid")
        }
        if(user.password.length <= 5) {
            throw InvalidUserException("Password should contain at least 6 characters")
        }
        if(user.password.isEmpty()) {
            throw InvalidUserException("Password cannot be empty")
        }
        if(user.confirmPassword.isEmpty()) {
            throw InvalidUserException("Confirm password cannot be empty")
        }
        if(user.password != user.confirmPassword) {
            throw InvalidUserException("Passwords does not match")
        }
        repository.insert(user)
    }
}
```

My repository:

```
class UserRepositoryImpl: UserRepository {
    private var auth: FirebaseAuth = Firebase.auth
    private var database: DatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users")

    override suspend fun insert(user: UserModel) {
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password).addOnCompleteListener {
            if(it.isSuccessful) {
                database.child(user.id.toString()).setValue(user)
            } else {
                //exception here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When this function is triggered, it navigates to another fragment and toasts the successful message, which is incorrect because the exception happens. 
Fragment:

```
private fun configEventFlow() = lifecycleScope.launch {
        viewModel.eventFlow.collectLatest { event ->
            when(event) {
                is RegisterViewModel.UiEvent.ShowToast -> {
                    toast(event.message)
                }
                is RegisterViewModel.UiEvent.SaveUser -> {
                    val action = RegisterFragmentDirections.actionRegisterFragmentToMainFragment()
                    findNavController().navigate(action)
                    toast(getString(R.string.register_successfully))
                }
            }
        }
    }

private fun configUserRegistration() = with(binding) {
        fabRegister.setOnClickListener {
            val email = editRegisterEmail.text.toString()
            viewModel.onEvent(RegisterUserEvents.EnteredEmail(email))
            val password = editRegisterPassword.text.toString()
            viewModel.onEvent(RegisterUserEvents.EnteredPassword(password))
            val confirmPassword = editRegisterPasswordConfirm.text.toString()
            viewModel.onEvent(RegisterUserEvents.EnteredConfirmPassword(confirmPassword))
            viewModel.onEvent(RegisterUserEvents.SaveUser)
        }
    }
```

ViewModel:

```
@HiltViewModel
class RegisterViewModel @Inject constructor(private val useCases: UserUseCases): ViewModel() {
    private val _email = MutableStateFlow<ResourceState<String>>(ResourceState.Empty())
    private val email: StateFlow<ResourceState<String>> = _email

    private val _password = MutableStateFlow<ResourceState<String>>(ResourceState.Empty())
    private val password: StateFlow<ResourceState<String>> = _password

    private val _confirmPassword = MutableStateFlow<ResourceState<String>>(ResourceState.Empty())
    private val confirmPassword: StateFlow<ResourceState<String>> = _confirmPassword

    private val _eventFlow = MutableSharedFlow<UiEvent>()
    val eventFlow = _eventFlow.asSharedFlow()

    fun onEvent(event: RegisterUserEvents) {
        when(event) {
            is RegisterUserEvents.EnteredEmail -> {
                _email.value = ResourceState.Success(event.value)
            }
            is RegisterUserEvents.EnteredPassword -> {
                _password.value = ResourceState.Success(event.value)
            }
            is RegisterUserEvents.EnteredConfirmPassword -> {
                _confirmPassword.value = ResourceState.Success(event.value)
            }
            is RegisterUserEvents.SaveUser -> {
                viewModelScope.launch {
                    try {
                        useCases.addUser(
                            UserModel(
                                id = System.currentTimeMillis().toInt(),
                                email = email.value.data!!,
                                password = password.value.data!!,
                                confirmPassword = confirmPassword.value.data!!
                            )
                        )
                        _eventFlow.emit(UiEvent.SaveUser)
                    } catch(e: InvalidUserException) {
                        _eventFlow.emit(UiEvent.ShowToast(message = e.message!!))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    sealed class UiEvent {
        data class ShowToast(val message: String): UiEvent()
        object SaveUser: UiEvent()
    }
}
```

Is there a way that I can manage this specific exception in this pattern? Even if I catch the exception there, the action is completed and my application follows at it was registered but in the database it does not occur because of the exception. Im sure that I'll have to face it again when login to handle specific exceptions from Firebase, which I cannot create this way but I have to receive them and display to the user. 
Any suggestions??
Sorry if it's missing any content, tell me and I update asap. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: "When this function is triggered, it navigates to another fragment and toasts the successful message" Can you share the code where the transaction is happening?

Comment: Updated with view model and fragment functions related